# Sorting C# DataTable by Column in 0:00:00 format

Tags: c#, csv

I am in a unique situation. I have 2 datatables that end up merged together.

```
        //make third combined datatable 
        DataTable dtAll = new DataTable();            

        dtAll.Merge(dt1);
        dtAll.Merge(dt2);

        dtAll.DefaultView.Sort = "TestTime ASC";
```

As you can see, with this current code, it appends the results of the second table onto the end of the first. I need this full data set sorted, by TestTime.

The issue is that TestTime is a "0:00:00" time format field (see below)

[image]

This code does nothing:

```
dtAll.DefaultView.Sort = "TestTime ASC";
```

Any help? Just need a way to sort by a 0:00:00 time format as shown above.

Comment: What type is it in the `DataTable`, a `String`? So what is `dtAll.Columns[0].DataType`

Comment: It is currently a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that `TestTime` is a `String`-column, isn't it? Then you could parse them to `TimeSpan` and use Linq-To-DataTable for the sorting:

```
dtAll = dtAll.AsEnumerable()
    .OrderBy(r => TimeSpan.Parse(r.Field<string>("TestTime")))
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

You could also use [`TimeOnly.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timeonly.parse?view=net-6.0#system-timeonly-parse(system-string)), it should work in the same way.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I get the following error when using this code. "'String was not recognized as a valid TimeSpan.'

Comment: @Eli: What string is invalid? I tried your samples and they work. If you don't know which exactly, move the parse code into a method and call that from the LINQ query. Then you can use a try-catch to see which is causing the exception.

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

you need first to accept  the new rows, then it sorts correctly

```
            dtAll.Merge(dt1);
            dtAll.Merge(dt2);

            dtAll.AcceptChanges();
            view = dtAll.DefaultView;
            view.Sort = "TestTime ASC";
```

[image]